# Android Google Maps authorization failure

Tags: java, android, google-maps, authorization, google-play-services

I have reviewed all similar questions regarding Google Maps authorization failure but it did not help.

`Google Maps Api v2` is enabled and correct.
Android Keys for Debug and Release builds are correct and their corresponding validation Package Names and Fingerprints are correct.

Now, the first strange thing is that `Google Maps` had been working perfectly for 1 and a half years and we did not register any errors until 23 May 2016.
We did not change anything in Google Dev Console or in Application that would be a threat to `Google Maps` functionality.

The second strange thing is that this error only occurs on Release builds and Debug builds are working fine. With this in mind I tried to generate another Android Key for maps (without package/fingerprint validation) but it did not help.

Android Manifest contains these permissions:

```
com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
INTERNET
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

We also use:

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="false" />
```

Play Services Maps API:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
```

Yes, this API is quite old but updating it to 8.4.0 did not help either.

Google Maps authorization failure we're getting:

```
E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Authorization failure.  Please see            https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
07-27 14:52:37.551  25002-25035/com.package.name E/Google Maps Android API﹕ In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
API Key: ******************************
Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): finger:print;com.package.name
```

If someone had any ideas on where or why such a problem could suddenly happen I would be more than happy with any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you generate your map key by account on which you will going to upload your app ?

Comment: No, the account is not the same, but read and write permissions to the project were given to employees responsible for application deployment or develepment.

Comment: By your ans desc I think there may be problem with misleading SHA of your system from where your apk is being generated.

Comment: Little update: I created a use-case where I manually crashed play services inside the app, and when I started the app second time they were working fine... So this confirms SHA should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try to use updated google map api 

 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'

  and check whether you had used these permission in app
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

 and used these meta tag within application
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/application_id" />  

      // as unauthorized occurs just because of invalid app id which created on google developer console
```